# Finding a basis of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ spanned by the vectors $(1,2,−1,0),(4,8,−4,−3),(0,1,3,4),(2,5,1,4)$.

I've tried reducing a matrix (with vectors as rows) to the triangular form and got $(1,2,-1,0), (0,1,3,4)\text{ and }(0,0,0,-3)$. A matrix with vectors as columns gives a different answer with four vectors, but two bases of the same vector space have the same number of elements. Is this correct?

Comment: $(2,5,1,4)=2(1,2,-1,0)+(0,1,3,4)$; row rank = column rank

Comment: So the three vectors I found give a linear combinations of the four given. They are also independent, therefore they are a basis for the given subspace, if I understand correctly. But which answer (the one with vectors as rows or columns) is correct?

Comment: You understand correctly.  What did you mean "a matrix with vectors as columns gives a different answer with four vectors"?

Comment: First I solved a matrix with the vectors given in the exercise as rows (horizontally). In the second case with the vectors in the vertical direction I got $(1,0,0,0), (4,-3,0,0), (0,4,3,0)$ and $(2,4,3,0)$.

Comment: Notice the fourth vector is twice the first vector plus the third

Comment: I'm not sure what specifically you're doing with the matrix with the given vectors as columns, but be aware that row reduction preserves the rowspace, but in general, does **not** preserve the columnspace. Consequently, the non-zero rows in the REF of the first matrix will span the subspace, but the columns of the REF of the second matrix will not necessarily even be in the subspace, let alone span it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to remember small silly examples that you should intuitively know the answer to immediately without any calculation required and check to see that your proposed method works for that silly small situation as well.

Here, think of the problem where we want to find a basis for the space spanned by the *single* vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

It should be painfully clear that the vector by itself *is* a basis (*or more correctly a set containing the vector is*).

Now, if we were to lay it sideways and row reduce., well, it is already in RREF, and we wind up with $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix},$ which as noted before can be interpreted as a valid basis for our space.

If instead we were to lay it as a column and then row reduce, well, that gives us $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, but this is not even an element of our space and so clearly is not a basis for it.

---

All of this is a long way of reminding you and giving you an easy way to remember what @TheoBendit mentioned above... that row reduction preserves the rowspace of a matrix, but can change the columnspace of a matrix.

That is to say, if you want to find a basis for a collection of vectors of $\Bbb R^n$, you may lay them out as rows in a matrix and then row reduce, the nonzero rows that remain after row reduction can then be interpreted as basis vectors for the space spanned by your original collection of vectors.

Comment: I think that it’s worth explaining that you _can_ find a basis by laying the vectors out as columns, but once you’ve found the pivot columns, you have to go back to the original matrix to get the actual basis vectors.